# Do auto attack blocks/dodges block empowered auto attacks?

Tags: league-of-legends

Jax's 'E' is "Counterstrike", which is to dodge any incoming auto attacks for 2 seconds and then stun nearby enemies + a bit of damage depending on how many auto attacks were blocked.

My question is, what would happen if say Nasus' Q (which is an empowered auto attack) were cast on a Jax with his E up?

Same for a mirror lane Jax with an auto attack empowered by his W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the previous answer don't have a full list, here are the abilities that Jax can dodge:

- Ezreal's Mystic Shot
- Fiora's Blade Waltz
- Fizz's Urchin Strike (only will dodge the physical damage of the skill - magical damage will still be dealt)
- Gangplank's Parrrley (considered as melee attack)
- Irelia's Bladesurge
- Lucian's Lightslinger
- Master Yi's Double Strike
- Miss Fortune's Double Up
- Renekton's Ruthless Predator
- Shyvanna's Twin Bite
- Twitch's Rat-tat-tat-tat
- Warwick's Infinite Duress
- Yauso's Steel Temepest

Jax can dodge hits from :

- Shaco's Hallucinate
- Yorick's Omen of Death
- Mordekaiser's Children of the Grave
- Le Blanc's Mirror Image (although it deals 0 damage it still applies on-hit effects)

Turret shots can't be dodged (credit to Jutschge)
When an ability is dodged, only the damage is mitigated, just like Fiora's W. The on-hit effects (CC, silence, etc.) will still be dealt.
Basically all abilities that proc on-hit effects can be dodged.
All the dodged abilities counts towards Counter Strike's increased damage.

So jax cannot dodge enhanced auto-attacks if they do not proc on-hit effects.
As such Jax will not be able to dodge Nasus' Q or opponent Jax's W.

If there's any that I missed out or any that shouldn't be here, feel free to edit.

Resources adapted from: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/

Answer (score 2):

Most empowered attacks cannot be dodged by Jax's E, however there are some exceptions to it. Mystic Shot (Ezreal Q) and Parrrley (Gangplank Q) for example are spells that apply on-hit effects and the damage of said abilities will be blocked by his dodge.

If you aren't sure about a certain attack you can check [Lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/). All empowered attacks have a note about their interaction with Dodge or Block.

Comment: A small question here - can Jax's E dodge turret shots?

Comment: @KimMinseo No. Turret shots can be blocked (pantheon) but not dodged.

Comment: Thx, have been looking for this since I wanted to know whether I could successfully turret dive with Jax E